# Using find within a for loop to extract portion of file names as a variable (bash)

Tags: bash, variables, for-loop, find

I have a number of files with a piece of useful information in their names that I want to extract as a variable and use in a subsequent step. The structure of the file names is samplename_usefulbit_junk. I'm attempting to loop through these files using a predictable portion of the file name (samplename), store the whole name in a variable, and use `sed` to extract the useful bit. It does not work.

```
    samples="sample1 sample2 sample3"
    for i in $samples; do
       filename="$(find ./$FILE_DIR -maxdepth 1 -name '$(i)*' -printf '%f\n')"
       usefulbit="$(find ./$FILE_DIR -maxdepth 1 -name '$(i)*' -printf '%f\n' | sed 's/.*samplename//g' | sed 's/junk.*//g')"
       (More steps using $usefulbit or $(usefulbit) or ${usefulbit} or something)
    done
```

`find ./$FILE_DIR -maxdepth 1 -name 'sample1*' -printf '%f\n'` and `find ./$FILE_DIR -maxdepth 1 -name "sample1*" -printf '%f\n'` both work, but no combination of parentheses, curly brackets, or single-, double-, or backquotes has got the loop to work. Where is this going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
for file in `ls *_*_*.*`
do
  echo "Full file name is: $file"
  predictable_portion_filename=${file_%%_*}
  echo "predictable portion in the filename is: ${predictable_portion_filename}"
  echo "---"
done
```

PS: $variable or ${variable} or "${variable}" or "$variable" are different than $(variable) as in the last case, $( ... ) makes a sub-shell and treats anything inside as a command i.e. $(variable) will make the sub-shell to execute a command named *variable*

In place of ls *_*_*.*, you can also use (to recursively find all files with that standard file name): ls -**1**R *_*_*.*

In place of using ${file%%_*} you can also use: **echo ${file} | cut -d'_' -f1** to get the predictable value. You can use various other ways as well (awk, sed/ etc).

Comment: Thanks, this helped me a lot.  This is what I ended up using: 
        `for i in directory/*.ext; do
         myfile="$i"
         name="$(echo $i | sed 's!.*/!!g' | sed 's/_junk*.ext//g')"
            some other steps
        done`

Answer (score 0):

Excuse me, i can't do it with bash, may i show you another approach?  Here is a shell (lua-shell) i am developing, and a demo as a solution for your case:

```
wws$ `ls ./demo/2
sample1_red_xx.png  sample2_green_xx.png  sample3_blue_xx.png

wws$ source ./demo/2.lua
sample1_red_xx.png: red
sample2_green_xx.png: green
sample3_blue_xx.png: blue

wws$
```

I really want to know your whole plan , unless you need bash as the only tool...
  Er, i fogot to paste the script:

```
samples={"sample1", "sample2", "sample3"}
files = lfs.collect("./demo/2")

function get_filename(prefix) 
    for i, file in pairs(files) do
        if string.match(file.name, prefix) then return file.name end
    end
end
for i = 1, #samples do
    local filename = get_filename(samples[i])       
    vim:set(filename)
    :f_lvf_hy
    print(filename ..": "..  vim:clipboard())
end
```

The 'get_filename()' seems a little verbose... i haven't finished the lfs component.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer my question! I'm not really familiar enough with some of your suggestions to fit them into what I'm trying to do, but I've found a simpler solution that suits my purposes.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether answering my own question with my final solution is proper stackoverflow etiquette, but this is what ultimately worked for me:

```
    for i in directory/*.ext; do
        myfile="$i"
        name="$(echo $i | sed 's!.*/!!g' | sed 's/_junk*.ext//g')"
        some other steps
    done
```

This way I start with the file name already a variable (in a variable?) and don't have to struggle with `find` and its strong opinions. It also spares me from having to make a list of sample names.

The first `sed` removes the directory/ and the second removes the end of the file name and extension, leaving a variable $name that I use as a prefix when generating other files in subsequent steps. So much simpler!